# How do I get "modes' with respect to another column in R?

Tags: r

As the title suggests, I need mode of a particular column W.R.T categories in another column

```
> table(data$Outlet_Size)

         High Medium  Small 
  1606    621   1862   1592 
> table(data$Outlet_Type)

    Grocery Store Supermarket Type1 Supermarket Type2 Supermarket Type3 
              722              3717               618               624
```

so, I want to find out what are the stores sizes W.R.T the types of these stores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Outlet_Size)) %>% #(Optional to exclude NA from mode)
  count(Outlet_Type, Outlet_Size,name = "mode") %>% 
  group_by(Outlet_Type) %>% 
  slice_max(mode)
```

Output:

```
  Outlet_Type       Outlet_Size  mode
  <chr>             <chr>       <int>
1 Grocery Store     Small         257
2 Supermarket Type1 Medium        250
3 Supermarket Type2 Medium        260
4 Supermarket Type3 Small         249
```

Input:

```
set.seed(123)
data = pivot_longer(setnames(
  as.data.frame(
    lapply(1:3, \(x) {
      sample(c("Grocery Store", "Supermarket Type1", "Supermarket Type2", "Supermarket Type3"),
             1000, replace=T)
      })),c("High", "Medium", "Small")
  ), everything(), names_to = "Outlet_Size", values_to = "Outlet_Type")
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked but there's one more issue I encountered, I am getting mode for grocery store as NA which I want to exclude
```data %>% 
+     count(Outlet_Type, Outlet_Size,name = "mode") %>% 
+     group_by(Outlet_Type) %>% 
+     slice_max(mode)
# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   Outlet_Type [4]
  Outlet_Type       Outlet_Size  mode
  <chr>             <chr>       <int>
1 Grocery Store     NA            370
2 Supermarket Type1 Small        1240
3 Supermarket Type2 Medium        618
4 Supermarket Type3 Medium        624```

Comment: just add `filter(!is.na(Outlet_Size)) %>%` before the `count()` - see edit